# DbNUll Exception while converting the result to Model Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I was using Entity Framework to query the db and generate the results
As a first step i was trying to find total no of records [ Since this is a server side pagination block] The code used to return total count is like below

```
//how many records in total
int totalResultsCount = await query.CountAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This is returning the result correctly. For my given query 24k records is showing as count

As a next step I am trying to convert the result to a model that i want and i was using the code like below

```
var dataset = await query.Select(c => new ContactListModel
{
    Id = c.Id,
    FirstName = c.FirstName,
    LastName = c.LastName,
    Email = c.Email,
    EmailAlternative = c.EmailAlternative,
    JobTitle = c.JobTitle,
    CompanyName = (c.Company != null) ? c.Company.Name : "",
    StatusValue = c.Status,
    Modified = c.Modified,
    AddressCountry =   (c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsPrimary) != null) ?
                       (c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsPrimary).Country!=null) ? c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsPrimary).Country.Name : "" 
                      :""                    
}).OrderByDynamic(sortBy, sortDirection).Paginate((tableState.Page * tableState.PageSize), tableState.PageSize).ToListAsync();
```

While executing this line of the code getting this exception

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String`
```

ContactListModel  all string properties are set to Nullable string , but still getting the same error

Is any way to know which property is causing the trouble as it is hard to find the entry causing issues from 24k results

The custom result model class looks like this

> public class ContactListModel
> {
> public int Id { get; set; }
>
> ```
>     public string Title { get; set; }
>
>     public string FirstName { get; set; }
>      
>     public string LastName { get; set; }
>
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Combines the first name last name and middle names to a single string seperated with spaces
>     /// </summary> 
>     public string Name
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             return string.Join(" ",
>                           new[] { Title, FirstName, LastName }
>                           .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
>                           );
>         }
>     }
>
>
>     public string Email { get; set; }
>
>     public string EmailAlternative { get; set; }
>
>     public string JobTitle { get; set; }
>
>     public string CompanyName { get; set; }
>
>     
>     //public ContactAddress Address { get; set; }
>
>     public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
>     public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
>     public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
>     public string AddressLine4 { get; set; }
>
>     public string AddressCountry { get; set; }
>
>     public string AddressCounty { get; set; }
>     public string AddressCountyText { get; set; } 
>     public string AddressPostCode { get; set; }
>     public string AddressTown { get; set; }
>      
>     public bool Modified { get; set; } = false;
>
>     public bool Checked { get; set; } = false;
>
>     public ContactStatus  StatusValue { get; set; }
>
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Convert the StatusValue to meaningful status to display in front end 
>     /// </summary>
>     public ContactStatus Status
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             if (StatusValue == ContactStatus.Verified)
>                 return ContactStatus.Active;
>             else
>                 return StatusValue;
>         }
>     } 
>
> }
> ```

Comment: Can you send the related class?  You did not get the result by removing each line, which field is it?I think about to the line below? "    CompanyName = (c.Company != null) ? c.Company.Name : "c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsPrimary) != null",
"

Comment: do you test this code  "return (c.Company == null or c.Company.Name == DBNull.Value) ? string.Empty : c.Company.Name"

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi related class added to question

Comment: No, the meaning, class  Base  of use the  query method. Because there it gives an error

Comment: you can set the table design to allow null and re-scaffold your model. using -force atribute

Comment: What is `query`? Doesn't seem to be an instance of `ObjectContext.CreateQuery<ContactListModel>()` or you wouldn't have to be doing any conversion yourself and dealing with `DBNull.Value`s.